# a pure comparison function in c++

Tags: c++

I want to created a generic sorted linked list. Thus I have an abstract class Data, with a pure operator< (in order to easily sort the list. I believe it is called a comperator.) Now I have a class Job which derives from Data and implements the operator. The problem rises when I try to create a list of jobs and find out that job is also abstract. It happens because the operator I wrote in Job doesn't have the exact same signature as in Data -
in data:

```
virtual bool operator<(const Data& other) const =0;
```

and in job:

```
virtual bool operator<(const Job& other) const;
```

I had to receive job in job's operator since I can't compare job to a generic data. But now the new operator just hides the old one instead of overriding it (or implementing it because it is pure).
How can I solve the problem without using downcasting?
Thanks!
Edit: and without templates.

Comment: This is why generic code in C++ usually uses compile-time polymorphism (templates) instead of runtime polymorphism (virtual calls).

Comment: You're basically asking "How do I solve this problem without using any of the solutions?".

Comment: Without downcasting or templates?  Impossible.  Since you insist templates aren't allowed, you'll have to give `Job` the same signature as `Data`, and cast it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using downcasting... seems like a job for templates.

You can enforce the implementation of the comparison function using the operator directly, and not necessarily declaring it as pure `virtual`. And it's also generic.

Same result, different approach. More flexibility, since you don't have to derive from something (which *can* become a pain if you start using multiple inheritance).

```
template<typename T>
class SortedLinkedList
{
    T* head;
    void insertItem(const T& item)
    {
       T* currentNode = head;
       //iterate
       {
          if ( *currentNode < item ) // force implementation of operator <
          { /* whatever */ }
       }
    }
};
```

Comment: I also can't use templates. And what to do you mean by forcing the implementation of the comparison function using the operator directly? Remember that Data must have the comparison operator so I can manipulate the generic list using the interface of data.

Comment: @user1330810 why can't you use templates? Forcing the implementation means that it won't compile if you don't define the operator. With no templates and no downcasting, I don't see how this is possible.

Comment: I see now what forcing the implementation means, and I even think it's  a better idea, but we've been instructed to create the list using inheritance and not templates.

Comment: Then how can you make something _generic_ without templates?

Comment: using an empty and abstract 'Data' class, creating a data list, and having any class who wished to be put into a list - derive from Data.

Comment: That's just silly.  Class writers shouldn't have to anticipate what kinds of collections people will want to put objects of their class in.  The class you're taking is dumb.

Comment: I totally and wholeheartedly agree.

Comment: @user1330810 one option would be to forward-declare all deriving classes, and have a virtual operator for each of them in the base class. But that's very ugly.

Comment: Another solution is to delete the pure comperator from data and make the list abstract with the sorted-addition function as pure, and make various lists derive from the abstract list. But then almost the entire sorted-addition function will be copied and pasted many times...